# How to delete multiple sub directories when file is empty

Tags: bash, if-statement, while-loop, terminal

I have multiple sub directories in a directory. Each directory contains a file named `files.txt`. I want to delete a sub directory which contains empty file named `files.txt` else not. I am using following script.

```
#!/bin/bash

    while [ -s */files.txt ]
    do
           line=pwd ;
           rm -r "$line" ;
    done
```

This is throwing error too many arguments. I also tried using

```
if [ -s */files.txt ]
then
       line=pwd
       rm -r "$line"
else
       echo "not empty"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above solution will also remove folders which do not ahve files.txt. If those folders are NOT to be removed, consider the following

```
You have to loop over the directories:

for d in */; do
    [ -f "$d/files.txt" ] || continue
    [ -s "$d/files.txt" ] || rm -rf "$d"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop over the directories:

```
for d in */; do
    [ -s "$d/files.txt" ] || rm -rf "$d"
done
```

**Note:** First test it, with `echo $d` instead of the `rm` command.